# A dplyr option for loops in base R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I want to run the following code for different values in `drug`:

```
drug <- c("A","B","C","D") 

tmp_A <- data %>%
            group_by(ID) %>%
            summarise(sum_A = sum(DRUG=="A", na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
            mutate(is_A = ifelse(sum_A>0, 1, 0))

tmp_B <- data %>%
            group_by(ID) %>%
            summarise(sum_B = sum(DRUG=="B", na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
            mutate(is_B = ifelse(sum_B>0, 1, 0))

tmp_C <- data %>%
                group_by(ID) %>%
                summarise(sum_C = sum(DRUG=="C", na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
                mutate(is_C = ifelse(sum_C>0, 1, 0))
```

etc.

Is there a way to do that using dplyr instead of for loops, without repeating the same lines each time?

Comment: Create a function to group, summarise, mutate etc  and then use lapply to store the result of each function call in a list.

Comment: Could you report the code?

Comment: yes a little bit later on I will.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your goal, especially the use of `is_A`, `is_B` etc, but if your goal is to get the number of ID in each DRUG, this may be suitable:

```
data %>% 
    count(ID, DRUG) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = DRUG, values_from = n, names_prefix = "sum_")
```

The code above is suitable in case the levels in DRUG column match `drug` elements, namely "A","B","C","D". In case there are different levels, filtering is needed:

```
matched_data <- data %>% filter(DRUG %in% drug)
matched_data %>% 
    count(ID, DRUG) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = DRUG, values_from = n, names_prefix = "sum_")
```